# Is it possible to pass parameters in a taxonomy term's aliased URL using clean URLs?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, hooks

I am trying to pass URL parameters and access them in a preprocess function. I have done a fair amount of research but did not find an answer. It works if I do the following /example?id=1, but that's quite ugly and non-SEO friendly. Clean URLs is much better.

Is it possible to pass parameters in a taxonomy term's aliased URL using clean URLs?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the arg() function can do this.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/arg/6.x

At the end of Drupal's .htaccess file, you can see how Drupal makes those URLs work by rewriting them to ?q= if they are not real files or directories. Without this, they would cause a 404 too.

In http://api.drupal.org/api/function/arg/6 you can see how it handles them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry for my late reply, it's been a hectic few days. I should have mentioned that I'm using Drupal 8, and the arg() function is deprecated in that version. I have updated my question. I know that there is a replacement way to get the URL using the following two lines of code

Comment: $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

Comment: $path_args = explode('/', $current_path);

Comment: But this does not allow the addition of parameters to the URL. When I add parameters to the URL I get a 404 error as Drupal treats it as part of the page I am requesting.